# How can I encrypt a large message with a 512 RSA key?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I want to encrypt a large message and perform a measurement with different key sizes.

```
public static void generate(int keylen)
{
    KeyPairGenerator keygen = null;
    try
    {
        keygen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    keygen.initialize(keylen);
    key = keygen.generateKeyPair();
}
```

When I select 512 as the key size, my program throws the following error message: **javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 53 bytes**

```
public static byte[] encrypt(String message, PublicKey pk)
{
    Cipher cipher = null;
    try
    {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pk);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] cipherText = null;
    try {
        ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return cipherText;
}
```

I know that the RSA algorithm can only encrypt data that has a maximum byte length of the RSA key length in bits divided with eight minus eleven padding bytes, i.e. number of maximum bytes = key length in bits / 8 - 11.

I also know that 512 is not secure. I want to measure different key sizes with their respective time e.g. 512, 1024, 2048, 4096.....

Is there a way to encrypt the message without using a hybrid method because I also need to measure the time.
I read that there is a method to divide the message into blocks. I am not sure how this works exactly.

Comment: what do you mean hybrid model? Is it that you dividing the messages into blocks? For optimal performance and resource utilization, look into how to do cryptography on a stream of data like an InputStream rather than doing cryptography on there whole data structure.

Comment: hybrid mode: you encrypt the data with a symmetric key, and encrypt that key with rsa (which is the recommended approach).

Comment: You can use a Key Management System. Fundamentally a KMS will provide you two things. An encrypted data key and a symmetric key, the encrypted key is mapped to the symmetric key on the KMS system. The encrypted key has no value on its own, you can send the encrypted key to the KMS server and get the symmetric key. Effectively, you can send the encrypted key + the encrypted payload, then on the other side, you can pluck out the encrypted key, call the KMS to get the symmetric key and decrypt the payload.

Comment: If you found out that you can encrypt 53 bytes with a 512er private key simply take your plaintext, cut off the first 53 characters and encrypt them, then use the next 53 characters and so on. Store the encrypted parts and for decryption decrypt each part and concatenate the decrypted texts. But beware,  RSA encryption is slow. For that reason we use the hybrid encryption. Why should be this not an option for you ?

Comment: @MichaelFehr+ of course just breaking into blocks, effectively ECB mode (although _standard Java_ crypto does _not_ implement that mode when you specify transform RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding; BouncyCastle uses the clearer mode name 'NONE') allows an active adversary to manipulate the ciphertext and create false plaintexts. You need to either change the encryption significantly, or add authentication; this is not really a programming issue and is covered on crypto.SX and security.SX. But the usual _recommendation_ is indeed just to use hybrid and avoid the problem in the first place.

Comment: Also you should know that measuring the time of Java code like that is pretty useless; it does not accurately predict how an actual Java program will perform (see the _thousands_ of Qs about Java benchmarking, which _is_ ontopic here) and it will not be even in the same county as the time for other non-Java implementations.

Comment: In Java, this just means calling `doFinal()` for each chunk of data. Note that 8 bytes of random padding (out of the 11 bytes overhead) is also not considered very secure, which makes the test even more meaningless. You'd aim for 16 bytes, although 12 bytes might suffice for smaller key sizes I presume.